# TIMESTAMPDIFF in MYSQL to calculate # of months between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

My server uses an older version of PHP, so I unfortunately can't use the $datetime1->diff($datetime2) method.

I am currently using the following code, but it doesn't really work:

```
$from = explode("-",date("Y-m-d",$recurring_invoices->start_date));
$to = explode("-",date("Y-m-d",$to_time));
$months = ($to[0]-$from[0])*12+$to[1]-$from[1];
```

It will calculate July 30th to June 1st as one whole month. It should only count dates from July 1st to June 1st as a whole month.

I noticed there was a MYSQL TIMESTAMPDIFF function, but I can't seem to get that to work either.

```
$query = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'$recurring_invoices->start_date','$from_time')";
print_r($this->queryResult($query));
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, from_date, to_date) FROM agenda";
print_r($this->queryResult($query));
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: So you want the number of whole months that have elapsed between two given dates? So 1 month and 10 days = 1, 26 days = 0, etc etc?

Comment: DaveRandom, yes! exactly. That's a good way to put it. I'm clearly not one with words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, <strike>but it is untested</strike> now [tested](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7dpxHj) and fixed:

```
list($startYear, $startMonth, $startDay) = explode('-', date('Y-n-j', $recurring_invoices->start_date));
list($endYear, $endMonth, $endDay) = explode('-', date('Y-n-j', $to_time));

$months = 0;
$months += ($endYear-$startYear) * 12;
$months += $endMonth - $startMonth;
if ($startDay > $endDay) {
  $months -= 1;
}

echo $months;
```

Comment: I had to slightly modify your code because it didn't completely work, but because I saw the way you set up the logic, I was able to do it! And it works! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `list($startYear, $startMonth, $startDay) = explode('-', date('Y-n-j', $recurring_invoices->start_date));
                    list($endYear, $endMonth, $endDay) = explode('-', date('Y-n-j', $to_time));

                    $months = 0;
                    $months += ($endYear-$startYear) * 12;
                    $months += $endMonth - $startMonth;
                    if($startDay > $endDay) {
                        $months = $months - 1;
                    }`

Comment: @steeped I just realise my mistake while I was out having a cigarette. I will edit my answer for future visitors with your code.